# Push notifications do not show for iOS devices

Tags: ios, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

On the Bluemix dashboard, I need to see the analytics information of the Push service for both iOS and Android devices. As you can see in the following screen shot, the analytics information for Android devices displays as expected:
[image]

However, as shown in this screen shot, the analytics information for iOS devices is missing:
[image]

What do I need to do to get the analytics information for iOS devices to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push Analytics is not enabled correctly for the application. A service connection needs to be made. Otherwise, the full push analytics data is not received and you see the `No version information available` message in the Bluemix dashboard. The [Push](http://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/ios#push) documentation explains how to initialize Push and enable notifications.